# RemoteCertificateValidationCallback with X509Certificate2

Tags: c#

```
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
    FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@"C:\openssl\bin\cert_key.p12", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(certificate.ValidateRemoteCertificate);
    Client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
```

The problem I have with the above code is that the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback only accepts the older X509Certificate not X509Certificate2 type as a parameter.  I need X509Certificate2 because the third-party API that I send SOAP request to requires version 2.

Answer (score 6):

The X509Certificate2 class has a constructor that takes a X509Certificate as parameter. So you can do this:

```
RemoteCertificateValidationCallback callback = delegate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslError) {
    X509Certificate2 certv2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);
    // more code here that sends soap request
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why that is a problem. `X509Certificate2` inherits from `X509Certificate` and can therefore be casted to one.

**EDIT:**

Furthermore `X509Certificate2` has a constructor that takes a filename so you don't need the `FileStream`. Also I don't see you using the `buffer` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Those three lines of code at the top are not even doing anything.  The `FileStream` never gets loaded into `buffer`, and the `X509Certificate2` is never actually loaded from anywhere!

The `X509Certificate2` has a constructor overload that takes a file name as its argument.  That's what you should be using if you want to load a cert from a file.

This non-loading of the certificate is probably why your callback isn't working.  It's also highly unusual for transport security to be used for a SOAP Service - if this is a follow-up to the other PayPal API questions then you don't need the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` at all, that's for transport security and most WCF uses message security.